# How can I clone Exception in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, synchronization, semaphore

I have a data updater thread that uses callbacks to return either result or an exception to a manager. I use semaphore to synchronize manager start and getting the results of a background thread's work (either result or a an exception). Manager is launched only by other threads by calling `runUpdate` that uses `synchronizer.tryAcquire()`. Other threads can try to get result from a manager at any time. So when that happens I check if background thread finished it's work by checking semaphore state. So to return a result I clone it by a constructor and than I release semaphore. But in a case of exception I cannot do this. I must either create a new Exception thus losing it's actual class and stack trace or release semaphore before throwing an exception and risk getting incorrect results (`getReturnedException()` can already return null or other exception).

```
private final Semaphore synchronizer = new Semaphore(1, true);

public List<Map<String, Object>> getResult() throws Exception {
    if (synchronizer.tryAcquire(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
        if (getReturnedException() == null) {
            List<Map<String, Object>> tempResult = new ArrayList<>(result);
            synchronizer.release();
            return tempResult;
        } else {
            Exception clonedEx = cloneException(getReturnedException()); //some way to clone an exception
            throw clonedEx;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Exception("Background thread is still working");
    }
}

public void processException(Exception ex, Thread thread) {
    setReturnedException(ex);
    synchronizer.release();
}
```

So is there a way to implement `cloneException` function?

Comment: You can throw it without cloning :) Also, your getReturnedException is null in the else branch. Are you sure?

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake. Edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to accomplish this without any cloning, as well as solve another problem, which is that you're currently not releasing `synchronizer` if you throw `clonedEx`. Try this instead:

```
Exception ex = getReturnedException();
try {
    if (ex == null) {  //Did you mean equals null here?
        List<Map<String, Object>> tempResult = new ArrayList<>(result);        
        return tempResult;
    } else {
        throw ex;
    }
} finally {
    synchronizer.release();
}
```

Comment: Yes I meant ex == null. Edited the post. I do know how this construction works (try { return false; } finally { return true; } will return true). But I'm not sure if this is the same when throwing an exception.

Comment: Per the official Java docs: "The finally block *always* executes when the try block exits". So the answer is yes, the `finally` is called whether an exception is thrown or your normal `return` statement occurs.

Comment: @musical_coder: Always, except when try/catch has a System.exit call or something really bad happens(Example : JVM error)

Comment: Seeing as your whole program is dead at that point, there ain't much you can do :) This approach I coded here prepares you for just about every "handleable" situation.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to clone the exception. You just need to release your resource in a `finally` block, so that it always happens.